# Почему возникает ошибка при подключении monolog в symfony 4?

Tags: php7, symfony4

Я пытаюсь подключить monolog в symfony 4 
сделал:

> composer require symfony/monolog-bundle

Пытаюсь подключить

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class BuildNotifications {
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

}
```

Создаю:

> $a = new BuildNotifications();

вродебы symfony сам должен его заинжектить но этого не происходит получаю ошибку:

> Too few arguments to function
>   App\Notifications\BuildNotifications::__const     ruct(), 0 passed in
>   /home/master/.../src/Command/TestCommand.php      on line 122 and
>   exactly 1 expected

Кто ни буть подскажет как это можно победить? RegistryInterface?

Comment: а разве не composer require monolog/monolog?

Comment: не помогло......

Answer (score 1):

Проблема в том, что объявляя конструктор класса BuildNotifications вы указали обязательный параметр, а вызывая его этот не передаете этот параметр. Symfony не сделает Вам волшебства.

Либо уберите параметр из объявления конструктора, либо передайте его.

Вам просто нужно создать объект класса LoggerInterface

`$logger = new ConsoleLogger($output, $verbosityLevelMap);`

и передать его в Ваш конструктор

`$a = new BuildNotifications($logger);`

Comment: А как тогда получить контенер с логером?

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под контейнером? Экземпляр класса логгера? Создать его вызвав конструктор и передать туда необходимые данные. Я не эксперт в симфонии. Мой родной фреймворки это Laravel. Я лишь указал Вам на ошибку связанную с синтаксисом php которую вы допустили.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы напрямую получаете экземпляр объекта через `$a = new BuildNotifications();` то необходимо указать все параметры. В вашем случае, исходя из примера надо поступить следующим образом:

класс BuildNotifications остается без изменений

TestCommand.php:

```
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class TestCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    private function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        ...
        // А вот здесь передадим в конструктор объект логера
        $a = new BuildNotifications($this->logger); 
        ...
    }
}
```